# C# Remove SplitContainer border?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image][image]

Hi, How can I remove the border that surrounds the splitcontainer.panel? 
As you can see in the picture the left is executed and the right VS. 
The panel have dock.left programmatically and form backcolor is the same as panel therefore I believe that is the border.
I've tried some code but don´t work including this but only work on tabcontrol:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
    // Hide the tab headers at run-time
    if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode)
    {
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        return;
    }

    // call the base class implementation
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

how can I hide this border? hlp pls :\

Comment: Dark gray part on your screenshot is some control which you have in panel?

Comment: There should be property of SplitContainer. Something like background, stroke or something.

Comment: --Dark gray part on your screenshot is some control which you have in panel? No its win8 window
--There should be property of SplitContainer.. I´ve see all properties none has this function :\

Comment: @LuisGranado I suggest you to add screenshot of your windows 8 application to make problem clear. Because I don't see any borders on win 7

Comment: @LuisGranado Perhaps you should also post your form `InitializeComponent()` method, it will help others to _repro_ your issue. It's really hard to tell what's wrong with your form based on screenshot only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer, though I have win7.

On picture below you have typical `SplitContainer`. It consists of:

- SplitContainer backcolor;
- Panel 1 backcolor
- Panel 2 backcolor
- parent container backcolor

[image]

On your screenshot you are editing form and in the designer mode you can see stroked lines which are representing panel margins. I have them too. It's ok.

What is not ok, is the left part of your screenshot. Suddenly your form is *inside* of something. This something cause this effect. I could think of either something has `Padding` (not `0;0;0;0`) or your form has `Margin` (not `0;0;0;0`) or perhaps it is some glitch, when, to example, you have your form embedded into something (another form), due to non-client region being not-painted or whatever else.

### Edit

Try to set colors explicitly (set some crazy colors, like I did) for: splitcontainer, panel1, panel2 and parent container (whatever it is). Then post a screenshot. I am pretty sure once you do it, you will see a problem.

Comment: you right I put green now can see where is the error. when I put dock.Left on panel he does not touch completely. What I do to touch?

Comment: Set `Padding` to `0;0;0;0` of that panel (on which you drop split container).

Comment: splitcontainer1.panel padding to 0;0;0;0 solves everything
thank you my friend I owe you a beer :)